# Issues with printing values from multiple arrays in python in the console

Tags: python, arrays, console

So I am trying to make a program that take in input for a flight, and stores it in arrays based on each type of input. Here are the arrays that I use to do this:

```
airline = []
flightNumbers = []
destination = []
gate = []
status = []
```

Here is the issue that I am having. After the user goes through and adds 1 flight, I want the program to print a flight status board in the console. For example if I enter:
 "Delta", "Dl1480", "Atlanta", "E11", "Ontime"
 "American", "AA367", "New York City", "H10", "Delayed"
 "United", "UA3411", "Louisville, KY", "F25", "Cancelled"
this is what I want to see output by the program:

```
airline:  | flight number:  | destination:     |  gate:  |  status:
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Delta     |  DL1480         |  Atlanta         |  E11    | Ontime
American  |  AA367          |  New York City   |  H10    | Delayed
United    |  UA3417         |  Louisville,KY   |  F25    | Cancelled
```

Here is what I tried to use to get this to print:

```
def showAll(self):
            print("Airline | Flight Number | Destination | Gate | Status")
            x = 0
            while x < len(a.airline):
                print(a.airline + [" | "] + a.flightNumbers + [" | "] + a.destination + [" | "] +  a.gate + [" | "]+  a.status + ["\n"])
                x += 1
```

but I get this as output if I enter 2 random entries:

```
Airline | Flight Number | Destination | Gate | Status
['delta', 'delta', ' | ', '001', '002', ' | ', 'Los angeles, ca', 'atlanta', ' | ', 'a1', 'a3', ' | ', 'ontime', 'ontime', '\n']
['delta', 'delta', ' | ', '001', '002', ' | ', 'Los angeles, ca', 'atlanta', ' | ', 'a1', 'a3', ' | ', 'ontime', 'ontime', '\n']
```

Can some suggest a way I can fix this, or a better way of going about this entirely? Here is the code for the entire program:

```
class FSB:
        # arrays to store flight information
        airline = []
        flightNumbers = []
        destination = []
        gate = []
        status = []
        input = ""

        def addFlight(self):

            while input != "bye":
                # get inputs
                air = input("Enter an airline name >> ")
                fn = input("Enter a flight number >> ")
                dest = input("Enter a destination >> ")
                g = input("Enter a gate number >> ")
                stat = input("Enter a flight status >> ")
                self.air = air
                self.fn = fn
                self.dest = dest
                self.g = g
                self.stat = stat


                # add inputs to appropiate arrays
                a.airline.append(self.air)
                a.flightNumbers.append(self.fn)
                a.destination.append(self.dest)
                a.gate.append(self.g)
                a.status.append(self.stat)
                print("Data stored sucessfully.\n")
                a.showAll()

        def showAll(self):
            print("Airline | Flight Number | Destination | Gate | Status")
            x = 0
            while x < len(a.airline):
                print(a.airline + [" | "] + a.flightNumbers + [" | "] + a.destination + [" | "] +  a.gate + [" | "]+  a.status + ["\n"])
                x += 1

            go = input("To add a new entry, enter 1.\nTo reprint list, enter 2.\nTo exit, enter 3.\n")
            if go == "1":
                a.addFlight()
            elif go == "2":
                for x in range(1,26):
                    print(" ")
                a.showAll()
            elif go == "3":
                exit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = FSB()
    a.addFlight()
```

Comment: You should use `self` instead of `a` inside the methods. You should not read inputs inside of the methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to concatenate a string `"|"` to your list. Please try doing `["|"]`instead.

Comment: So that fixed my original issue, but now it prints that same entry 5 times. What kind of loop should I use to make sure that it prints one flight entry once only?

Comment: Try doing `a.airline[x]` ? Alternatively try using a `while` loop where you manually increment.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up iterating through each array manually, and this is what I got:

```
  def showAll(self):
            print("Airline\t\t\t" +"| Flight Number\t\t" +"| Destination\t\t" +"| Gate \t\t" +"| Status")
            for x in range(len(a.airline)):
                print("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
                print(str(a.airline[x] + "\t\t") + str(a.flightNumbers[x] + "\t\t") + str(a.destination[x] + "\t\t\t\t") + str(a.gate[x] + "\t\t")  + str(a.status[x]))
```

Thank you to everyone who suggested an answer, I appreciate it!